# Accesing routes that are JWT protected with EJS

Tags: jquery, node.js, jwt, ejs

So I have node/express app with jwt implemented and it is restful API. So until now, I just communicated with jsons.

Now I want to implement some functionalities like admin panel, and it should be located within my app.

So here is admin.js :

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const createError = require('http-errors');
const { admin } = require('../config');
const { aW, isAdmin } = require('../helpers');
const jsonwebtoken = require('jsonwebtoken');

// preappended route: /admin

router.get('/', aW(async (req, res) => {
    res.render('adminLogin');
}))

router.post('/login', aW(async (req, res) => {
    const { username, password } = req.body;
    if (!(username == admin.username && password == admin.password)) throw createError(401, 'Unauthorized');

    const token = jsonwebtoken.sign({ type: 'admin' }, admin.jwt, { expiresIn: '2h' });
    res.json({ token: 'JWT ' + token });
}))

router.use(isAdmin); // middleware to check if user is admin

router.get('/dashboard', aW(async (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', { title: 'admin' })
}))
```

So hitting ***/admin*** works fine and renders the form. Also, thru that form and ajax call, I pass the params and get the JWT token from route ***/admin/login***. On success of this call, I get the token.

Now, my question is, how do I change href of page to go to ***/admin/dashboard*** and pass that JWT token in header, so I get rendered that index page. Currently, I only get 'Unauthorized' message (since I didn't pass JWT).

My current logic for login is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var JWT = null;

    $('#adminLogin').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/admin/login',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {username: $('#adminLoginUsername').val(), password: $('#adminLoginPassword').val()},
            success: function(data) {
                JWT = data.token;
                window.location.href = '/admin/dashboard';
            }
        })
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Now you have the JWT from login screen. You should provide the Authorization header when calling the protected API. To Set the Authorization header you can do :

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        /* Set the Authorization header here*/
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + JWTToken;
    },
    success: function (data) {

    },
    error: function (jqXHR, status, error) {

    }
});
```

This is the great article for JWT Authentication :
https://fullstackmark.com/post/13/jwt-authentication-with-aspnet-core-2-web-api-angular-5-net-core-identity-and-facebook-login

Comment: That ajax works, and I get the JWT from it (without header auth), but now I need to access **/admin/dashboard**, how do I pass header in that route and change href? Also, method is 'GET' for this route (like I wrote in node code)

Comment: Href is just the link to that route there is no logic like how you want to pass the access. But From that page, if it tries to access the API's they all need to pass the authorization header just like above.

Comment: Did you actually read that article? You need to implement the Authentication Service that will take care of your JWT. You will maintain all the Request (Get/Post/Put/Delete) from single service which will access the Authentication Service and see if it has JWT Token; If it has then that will set the Authorization header. That's it... Every other pages are just pages which will consumes the services. You will maintain routes from page to page, user will navigate within the app .